# I cannot reference a function defined in a js file

Tags: javascript

There is a js file called `datetime.lib.js` which I created and which I attached to my page. Here is its content :

```
/**
    * convertir le format de la date YYYY-MM-DD en DD-MM-YYYY 
    * @access public   
    **/
    function convertDateFormat($str,$ch) {
        var $tmp="";
        if($str=="") $tmp="";
        else{
           $tmp=$str;
           var $Y=$tmp.substr(0,4); 
           var $M=$tmp.substr(5,2); 
           var $D=$tmp.substr(8,2);        
           $tmp=$D+$ch+$M+$ch+$Y;
        }
        return $tmp.trim();
    }

    /**
    * formatter une datetime MySQL "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mi:ss" en "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mi"
    **/
    function convertDateFormat2($str,$ch) {
        var $tmp="";
        if($str=="") $tmp="";
        else{
           $tmp=$str;
           var $Y=$tmp.substr(0,4);
           var $M=$tmp.substr(5,2);
           var $D=$tmp.substr(8,2);
           var $h=$tmp.substr(11,2);
           var $m=$tmp.substr(14,2);
           $tmp=$D+$ch+$M+$ch+$Y+" "+$h+"<b>:</b>"+$m;
       }
       return $tmp.trim();
    }

    function convertDateFormat3($str)
    {
       var $tmp=$str;
       if ($tmp != '') {
           var $Y=$tmp.substr(6,4); 
           var $M=$tmp.substr(3,2); 
           var $D=$tmp.substr(0,2);
           $tmp=$Y+"-"+$M+"-"+$D;
       }
       return $tmp.trim();
    }
```

The attachment ( in the footer ) :

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="<?php echo HTTP_JS ?>datetime.lib.js"></script>
```

where HTTP_JS equals to `'http://'.  $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] .'/'.SITE.'/javascript/'`

When I reference the two first functions in the js file then everything is ok , but when I call the last function then I get a console error : `ReferenceError: convertDateFormat3 is not defined`

So what is wrong ?

Comment: Why can't the `src` be relative?

Comment: You have to reference the functions **after** the `<script>` tag in the DOM. Otherwise, you have to execute the JS using an `onload` event listener.

Comment: Can you show the piece of code you are referencing those functions?

Comment: I call it like this : `$('#cacher').on("change", function() {
 var x = convertDateFormat3("12/10/2015"); 
 alert("D = "+x);
});`

Comment: Well, this way doesn't seems to cause any erros. Can you check if the scripts is rendered correctly on your html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you ever check the js file content in the webbrowser probably you edit this function at the end, and your browser is caching the last file version, you can check by going into the developers options -> debuggin and select your js file to check if the function is declare.

Comment: just F12 and then go to debuggin tab and find your file to check the code.

Comment: Ok , the function is not there ! so what to do ?

Comment: ok, you have two possible causes:
1: cache problem, do a CTRL+F5 to force to reload js.
2: you haven´t update the file on the server, and your datetime.lib.js really don't have that function code, so just upload it to your ftp.

Comment: OK , I clear all cache and it works now ! thank you very much :)